# More efficient line of code in Java

Tags: java

I work with strings in my programs for many times.

Is there a way to do this line of Java code more efficient:

```
String str2 = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

Comment: I don't really think so (other than hidden away in a commons library) and by the way, you're only removing spaces in the middle, not tabs, linefeeds, etc, I think....

Comment: Trim first and then replace like `String str2 = str.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ").` because sometimes, larger trailing spaces would be trimmed in one shot!

Comment: Where the strings are comming from? If they are the result of a database query, I would try to let the database do the work (at least as much as possible).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a pre compiled pattern:

```
private Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\s+" );
```

And then use it like so:

```
str2 = p.matcher( str.trim() ).replaceAll( " " );
```

A more complex version that doesn't require trimming:

```
private Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^\\s+|\\s+(?= )|\\s+$" );

str2 = p.matcher( str ).replaceAll( "" );  // no space
```

Comment: Thank you. But more complex version will not work there is any any tabs or line feeds in the middle of the string.

Comment: Sorry, you can try `(?=\\s)` instead of `(?= )`, but I think the simpler version would be better. You can also try moving the trim to after the replaceAll and see how that works - performance wise.

Comment: (?=\\s) will change to tabulation or line feed or something else. But I want change to space, not any other whitespace.

Comment: (?=\\s) isn't for the replacement character, its part of the pattern being looked for. `(?= )` means look ahead for a space, while `(?=\\s)` means look ahead for any white-space character.